# Method not called when using Spring JMS namespace

Tags: java, spring, jms

I have an application which is built on Spring 3.0.5 and uses JMS for exchanging messages. The beans which receive the messages are configured by using the `jms` namespace. The class looks like this

```
class MyService {
    public void receive(String msg) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The Spring configuration looks like this

```
<jms:listener-container destination-type="queue">
  <jms:listener destination="queue.test" ref="myService" method="receive"/>
</jms:listener-container>
```

However, when I change the receive method to get a `Message` object the method is no longer called.

```
class MyService {
    public void receive(TextMessage msg) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I realize that I could just use the `MessageListenerAdapter` but it is more configuration overhead and I am just wondering why this doesn't work.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I've figured out is that in order for the `MessageListenerAdapter` **not** to convert the message the `messageConverter` attribute must be set to `null`. However, when using the namespace configuration it is not possible to disable the default message converter that is automatically created.

The code in the `AbstractListenerContainerParser` checks if the `message-converter` attribute of the `<jms:listener-container>` is either not set or points to a valid bean. Otherwise a `SimpleMessageAdapter` is instantiated.

To work around this problem I've created a `NoopMessageConverter` which solves the problem

```
public class NoopMessageConverter implements MessageConverter {
    @Override
    public Message toMessage(Object object, Session session) 
        throws JMSException, MessageConversionException {
        return (Message) object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object fromMessage(Message message) 
        throws JMSException, MessageConversionException {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Then configure the `<jms:listener-container>` like this

```
<bean id="noopMessageConverter" class="NoopMessageConverter"/>

<jms:listener-container message-converter="noopMessageConverter">
    <jms:listener destination="queue.test" ref="myService" method="receive"/>
</jms:listener-container>
```

Then you can create your bean as follows and the `receive` method is called

```
class MyService {
    public void receive(TextMessage msg) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `<jms:listener>` config automatically creates a `MessageListenerAdapter` for you, so it's not necesarry for you to configure that explicitly.

Your problem is that `MessageListenerAdapter` is designed to decouple your code from the JMS API altogether. The target method in `<jms:listener>` must declare one of the parameter types permitted by `MessageListenerAdapter` (see [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-receiving-async-message-listener-adapter)), which represent the possible payload types of a message, i.e. one of `String`, `Serializable`, `byte[]` or `Map`.

If you want to receive the raw JMS `TextMessage` object, then your listener class has to implement `MessageListener` or `SessionAwareMessageListener`. That makes it a "proper" JMS listener.  In that case, the `method` config becomes redundant, and you can just use :

```
<jms:listener destination="queue.test" ref="myService"/>
```

I'm actually rather surprised that Spring didn't throw an exception when it found that your `receive` method had an invalid parameter type.

Comment: The point is that the `MessageListenerAdapter` is perfectly capable of calling a method which expects a raw `Message` object. The docs even contain an example with the `DefaultTextMessageDelegate`. In my case I need to have access to the message properties. Implementing a `MessageListener` interface means that I can have only one method in that class which then needs to dispatch incoming messages from multiple queues to other methods.

Comment: I guess the `<jms:listener>` configures a default `MessageListenerAdapter` but in order to get the raw message you may need to disable the content extraction by setting the message converter to `null`. However, that doesn't seem to be possible with the `<jms:listener>`.